# Streaming video from Facebook

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming

I want to stream a video from Facebook to my site and use my own custom video player (flowplayer for instance) to play it. Basicly I want to access the registered user's videos and play them in my application. is it possible? If it is, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly easy, but there are a few steps to go thru.

1. Grab a list of their videos from the Graph API `me/videos` using their user access_token
2. Present user with list of their videos, let user select video to watch.
3. For the `id` of the video selected, call the Graph API and FQL the `src` or `src_hq` which gives you the link to the mp4 of the video
4. Point your custom player to the mp4 link.